# unable to Firebase deploy - function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I upgrade all the version of Firebase and node.js.

I ran the command line - npm upgrade firebase-tools -g

However, I keep receiving the error below when I try to deploy the function.

> functions: You are using an old version of firebase-functions SDK (3.16.0). Please update firebase-functions SDK to >=3.20.0

Answer (score 0):

The error is not referring to the CLI provided by the firebase-tools package.  It's referring to the firebase-functions package that you use to define your functions in code. You need to update that instead.  `npm install firebase-functions@latest`